# External properties @configurationProperties style prefix for proprties with not predefined structure

Tags: java, spring-boot, configurationproperties

I have some properties, where some initial part is same and remaining is different for all properties.
can have 1 dot (.) 2,3 or more.
I can't use `@ConfigurationProperties` to loca these with `prefix ="com.some.props"` because remaining properties are different

```
com:
 some:
  props:
     prop1:
       someProp: value
     prop2:
        anotherProp:
         innerprop: value2
```

So I created a custom props class and used `@Value` but I have to write full property path for wach variable.
Is there a way I can apply a prefix for all `@Value` in a class

```
@Component (prefix="com.some.props") //Not a valid code, but want something of this sort.  
class props {
   @Values ("${prop1.someprop}")
   String someprop;
   @Values ("${prop2.anotherProp.innerProp}")
   String somethingElse;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `public static class Prop1Properties`?

Comment: I don't want to make classes for one property. Just want to have one property class and all the properties populated in it.

Comment: Why, specifically? Nested classes for nested properties is how Spring Boot itself handles these things.

Comment: all the properties are of different structure, as I said in question. So I've to either rename the properties (Its migration project) or create too many internal classes in my ConfigProperties class..... I know that's the spring standard way....as you are recommending... but wanted to ask, if there is something to achieve what I requested......   :)